# get more than 20 members of a list with ruby, twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am using Twitter gem (1.7.1) in ruby. I want to get my member of my list on Twitter but I just get last twenty members. How can I get more than twenty members?

```
listmembers = client.list_members(username, listname)
listmembers.users.each do |lmname| 
              p lmname.screen_name
            end
```

Comment: can you show us a little bit of code so we can see how you're currently doing things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, pass an argument "cursor=-1". You then get the first 20. The Twitter API will return a field called "next_cursor" - pass this to the cursor and you get the next 20.

Example (pseudocode):

```
cursor = -1
do {
    # get data, using the cursor
    data = {}

    cursor = data.next_cursor
} while (len(data) > 0) # Loop while we're still getting data back
```

More info on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/lists/members

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as the answer if it works! :-)

Comment: That's shady. Tom helped you solve the problem, but you did not give him credit for it. Two days later, you create your own answer, and give your own answer the credit.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with using "cursor". This solution helped me quite.
[How to use Twitter Api To Get more than 20 list Members in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422669/how-to-use-twitter-api-to-get-more-than-20-list-members-in-a-single-request)

I edited the code for ruby. My code is that; I kept an integer value,

```
pagevalue = 0
if (listmembers.next_cursor == 0) # it means we have only one page
  listmembers.users.each do |lmname| 
     p lmname.screen_name
  end
end
else # it means we have pages more than one
  while (listmembers.next_cursor != 0)
     listmembers.users.each do |lmname| 
        p lmname.screen_name # check screen_name is nil or not
      end
   end
   pagevalue = listmembers.next_cursor
   listmembers = client.list_members(username, listname, :cursor => pagevalue)
   if (listmembers.next_cursor == 0) # for last page
     listmembers.users.each do |lmname|
     p lmname.screen_name
   end
  end
end
```

if you get screen_name nil in while it won't work. So, check your screen_name if it exists or not.

Comment: Thanks.  This works.  Please, however, fix the formatting before I upvote this.

Comment: This answer is extremely redundant and self-serving as @TomvanderWoerdt has handed you the answer in proper DRY code.  You've simply taken his answer 2 days later and actually made it harder to read and understand and increasing the chances of a novice error.  You've used this as an opportunity to abuse the system here to give yourself points.  very shady, indeed.

Comment: @FlakDiNenno I didn't ignore TomvanderWoerdt answer. His answer helped me quite. But I asked about rails and I wanted to share my code, it is more about rails. Thanks for your interest! ;)

Comment: His answer **IS** in rails!  You should have awarded @TomvanderWoerdt with the answer to this, not yourself.  You could STILL have provided another answer *as you did*, but TomvanderWoerdt should have been awarded with the ACCEPTED SOLUTION

Comment: Stolen answer, you should have marked his as the answer